# Excel IF Statement for finding multiple words

Tags: excel, if-statement

My current formula looks like this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Hunter",I60,1), "1"),"No")
```

Basically this searches the text to find out if the cell contains the word "Hunter", if it finds the word, it will paste the number 1 and if the word is not in there, puts the word "No". I want to include multiple IF statements within that, for example if the the word Hunter is found then 1, but also if the word Verint is found then 2 and if Transact is found in there then number 3 - However I also want to keep the clause if none of them are found in there, to paste "No".

Could anyone help.

Thanks!

Comment: What if more than one of those words is found?

Comment: The data set I'm using is only 180 rows, I have noted there are no cells with more than one of those words.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Hunter",I60)),1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Verint",I60)),2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Transact",I60)),3,"No")))`

Please note that if the I60 contains "Verint Transact Hunter" it will only display value "1"

### Edit:

If you would like to keep track of all 3 values, adapt your formula to something like:

`=IF((AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Hunter",AM5)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Verint",AM5)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Transact",AM5)))),"1 2 3")`

^for all 3, note you need to make a specific clause for each combination, i.e. one for "1 and 3", one for "2 and 3" and one for "1 and 2"